# Simple parameterized sqlite query using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite

When running the query in the code below `err` is `null` and `row` is undefined. I know that the row is there.

I have this:

```
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./state.sqlite');

const hasBeenProcessed = (messageId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            db.get('SELECT id FROM messages WHERE id = ?', [messageId], (err, row) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(row != null);
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}

hasBeenProcessed(100)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(`Response was ${result}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: `row != null` returns a Boolean. I'm not sure if that is the intended value to resolve the Promise to.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion.  I would promisify all callback type functions.  Just makes code way easier to reason about, keeps it consistent, etc.  See if this will work:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./state.sqlite');

db.get = promisify(db.get);

const hasBeenProcessed = async (messageId) => db.get('SELECT id FROM messages WHERE id = ?', [messageId]);

hasBeenProcessed(100)
    .then(row => {
        console.log(`Response was ${row}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```